# XSLT - Output contents of a file (embed contents of a .css in generated .html)

Tags: xslt

is there a way to output the contents of a file in XSLT?
Background: 
I have an xml file as input for a xslt stylesheet and generate an html file, which links to a css. So far so good.

Now I want to change my xslt in a way that the contents of the css is embedded within the html file (using a `<style>` element). However, I would like to keep the xslt and css separated, if possible.

Thanks!
Nang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with XSLT 2.0

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unparsed-text

> The unparsed-text function reads an
>   external resource (for example, a
>   file) and returns its contents as a
>   string.
>
> The $href argument must be a string in
>   the form of a URI. The URI must
>   contain no fragment identifier, and
>   must identify a resource that can be
>   read as text. If the URI is a relative
>   URI, then it is resolved relative to
>   the base URI from the static context.

Comment: +1: Cool. However, like so often: Is there also a way in XSLT1.0?

Comment: @nang: XSLT 1.0 ony works with tree (allready parsed XML document, as example). So, if your CSS stylesheet can't be provided as a tree, there will be no solution in XSLT 1.0